# SonarQube Maven Java Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar

Tags: java, maven, plugins, sonarqube

SonarQube loves print me ERROR:

`Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project demo: The folder 'xyz\pizzav2\PizzeriaFinalFinal\src\test\java' does not exist for 'com.example.pizza:demo' (base directory = xyz\pizzav2\PizzeriaFinalFinal) -> [Help 1]`

xyz - my short path ;)

[image: Printscreen]

I'm lost 10 days for this problem with SonarQube.

Thank you very much for any help...

Comment: Hello Wifi, I am not saying I have the solution, but do you mind pasting here your setup from your pom file? Such as: <properties> <sonar.java.source> <sonar.binaries>  <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths> <sonar.java.coveragePlugin> <sonar.java.libraries> <sonar.junit.reportsPaths>  <sonar.language>  <sonar.scm.provider> <sonar.test.exclusions> <sonar.pullrequest.github.repository> etc please? Also, do you mind telling us a bit more about the Sonar server setup/version? How are you running the scan? Through sonar:sonar? is it reproducible with <version>3.7.0.1746</version>?

Comment: Don't paste log output as a picture, log it as text.  I can't even read that.  The error message indicates that you're telling sonarqube that the "src/test/java" directory exists, but apparently it does not.  Show your sonar properties and your folder structure if the problem isn't obvious to you by now.

Comment: Open the image in "new card" :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA9ET.png

Comment: Do `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar` instead of only `mvn sonar:sonar`...

Comment: When i'am trying mvn clean verify sonar:sonar i get error:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.pizza:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

My file pom in pastebin. How I give you configuration Sonar? Whats file? I run Sonar by SonarStart.bat file.

```
https://pastebin.com/DVn9WFTF
```

Wrapper.conf

```
https://pastebin.pl/view/1a8d7634
```